# $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_{pq})$ isomorphic to $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_{p})\times GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_{q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, general-linear-group

I was trying to solve the problem of finding the number of elements of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_m)$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. The case where $m=p$ prime was easy because of elementary linear algebra. The case $m=p^r$ was quite harder but using some group theory I was able to compute the elements of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k+1}})$ from the numbers of element of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_{p^k})$. But now I am stuck in the general case, I'm not sure whether this is right or not, but my intuition tells me that I can generalize the chinese remainder theorem ( $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}\cong\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_q$ if $\gcd(p,q)=1$) to $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_{pq})\cong GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_{p})\times GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_{q})$  if $\gcd(p,q)=1$. If this where true I would be able to finish the exercise, however I don't know how to do it.

Any hints or help will be thanked.

Comment: For $\gcd(p,q)=1$, the natural homomorphism $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_{pq})\to GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_{p})\times GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_{q})$ is surjective by the CRT (and the determinant in $R^\times$ characterization of $GL(R)$) and it is clearly injective.

Comment: $GL_2(\mathbb{Z_6}) $ is it a group?

Comment: @TOTANGHOSH  Yeah, the only possible problem is that the multiplication of two  matrices of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z_6})$ is not in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z_6})$ but it is easy to show that $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{Z_r})$ iff $det(A)$ is coprime with $r$.

Comment: So, diagonal matrix with diagonal entry $2 \in \mathbb Z_6$ not in $GL_2(\mathbb Z_6) $ @Marcos

Comment: @TOTANGHOSH yes, but this doesn't affect to the group.

Comment: But in that case $det(A)=4$ is not prime to $6$. @Marcos

Comment: @TOTANGHOSH yes, so this matrix is not in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z_6})$.

Comment: Okay, i.e $det(A)  \neq 0$ not imply that $A \in {GL_2(\mathbb Z_6) }$ @Marcos

Comment: @TOTANGHOSH you're right, maybe I should have said it, but i've defined $ GL_n(\mathbb {Z}_r)$ to be the $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $ \mathbb{Z}_r$ which are invertible, instead of the usual definition for $r$ prime which is the matrix with non-zero determinant.

Comment: Okay, thanks, now I got it..@Marcos